# Como puedo insertar múltiples registros a una tabla utilizando Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Hola cordial saludo espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo 2 tablas `compras` y `detalle_compra` lo que quiero es que el usuario agregue productos y los productos se agreguen a un listado(esto ya lo logre utilizando dataTables). Ahora mi pregunta es ¿como puedo insertar el detalle de esa compra teniendo en cuenta que hay varios productos en la lista?, la idea es que registre varios registros a la vez en la base de datos.

Espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes comenzar editando tu pregunta y mostrando lo que has intentado o investigado, para basados en eso poderte dar una respuesta más completa.

Comment: Intenta con un simple recorrido de la lista de compras y por cada elemento su insert.